# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Sage API

Tags: api, sage

When sending a post request through the Sage API to do a GLTransaction, using the GLTransactionPost query I receive the issue: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Is it Microsoft SQL Server side, as in the database settings, or is there a problem in the way I am requesting the Post request? And how can I go about debugging and/or fixing this issue.

I have made GET requests using the API before, but now with the POST request I am having this issue.

The API URL I am using is:

```
http://<IP>:5000/freedom.core/<Database Name>/sdk/rest/GLTransactionPost
```

and the body I am using is:

```
<GLTransactionPost xmlns="http://Freedom.PastelEvolution.co.za/Freedom.Core/2014/04/25">
 <batch xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Evolution.Services.SDK.Dto" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.
org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Hash i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Freedom.Core.Helpers" xmlns:b="http://sch
emas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
 <a:Transactions>
 <a:GLTransactionPostDto>
 <a:TxDate>2022-10-10T00:00:00</a:TxDate>
 <a:Reference>XMLTest</a:Reference>
 <a:TransactionCode>DT</a:TransactionCode>
 <a:Description>XMLTest</a:Description>
 <a:AccountCode>1000</a:AccountCode>
 <a:Debit>115</a:Debit>
 </a:GLTransactionPostDto>
 <a:GLTransactionPostDto>
 <a:TxDate>2022-10-10T00:00:00</a:TxDate>
 <a:Reference>XMLTest</a:Reference>
 <a:Description>XMLTest</a:Description>
 <a:TransactionCode>Credit</a:TransactionCode>
 <a:AccountCode>Levies Received</a:AccountCode>
 <a:Credit>115</a:Credit>
 </a:GLTransactionPostDto>
 </a:Transactions>
 </batch>
</GLTransactionPost>
```